# Cassandra internal working without joins

Tags: cassandra

How Cassandra works without joins and how it solve joins problem and sub queries.
I mean SQL uses joins so we can get result from different tables easily but how Cassandra do this job of getting rows from different tables because they say that Cassandra does not have join and sub queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you do not get data from multiple tables.

The long answer is that you plan your data model such that your tables all answer specific questions of your application. This makes it so that no query ever requires data from more than one table. So if for example your application requires data about particular users you would build a table that is structured around looking up information given a particular user. The analogy in the RDBMS world is materialized views.

Look into these videos for more information on denormalization and data modeling the Cassandra way.

[C* Summit 2013: The World's Next Top Data Model - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdJlsOZVGwM)
[The Weather Channel: CQL (Cassandra Query Language) Under the Hood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CY5-bWpqAVA)